# In Unreal Engine 5, how do I include and use UPlayMontageCallbackProxy::CreateProxyObjectForPlayMontage in C++?

Tags: c++, animation, include, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I want to play my `UAnimMontage` via C++, and in particular, want to make use of the conveniences of `UPlayMontageCallbackProxy`.

Looks like in theory, I can use `UPlayMontageCallbackProxy::CreateProxyObjectForPlayMontage`, but anytime I use it, I just get linker errors:

```
0>YCharacterVaulting.cpp.obj: Error LNK2019 : unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl UPlayMontageCallbackProxy::PlayMontage(class USkeletalMeshComponent *,class UAnimMontage *,float,float,class FName)" (?PlayMontage@UPlayMontageCallbackProxy@@QEAAXPEAVUSkeletalMeshComponent@@PEAVUAnimMontage@@MMVFName@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl UYCharacterVaulting::Traverse(void)" (?Traverse@UYCharacterVaulting@@QEAAXXZ)
```

I’ve already updated my `Build.cs` so that the module is included:

```
PrivateDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] {"AnimGraphRuntime", "MotionWarping"});
```

Any ideas on how I can fix the linker error? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have link errors because the engine developers have choosen not to export the UPlayMontageCallback class (or it is an oversight).
If we compare the declaration in the header file:

```
class UPlayMontageCallbackProxy : public UObject
```

... to another class in the same module which is exported:

```
class ANIMGRAPHRUNTIME_API UAnimExecutionContextLibrary : public UBlueprintFunctionLibrary
```

... you will notice the ANIMGRAPHRUNTIME_API macro which is exporting that class.